# How do I interpret this Inceptionv3 model graph

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I'm sorry if this question is really obvious or really basic for you guys I'm just a high school student trying to understand neural nets. Hey I've been researching a lot on image classification and I encountered this illustrating the Inception-v3 model:
 [image: this]

I'm not used to these types of illustrations, can someone go through what each rectangle means and why the model does not have layers that look like typical neural network illustrations with distinct layers like this:
 [image: this]

Comment: are you familiar with "convolution" layer in neural nets?

Comment: https://adeshpande3.github.io/A-Beginner%27s-Guide-To-Understanding-Convolutional-Neural-Networks/ You can go through this link to get basic understanding of what CNN is. Then it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to point to you to the right directions. Google's inception is a bit harder to understand.

The first thing to get into is convolutional layers, for that I recommend you [this guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-intuitive-guide-to-convolutional-neural-networks-260c2de0a050). This will explain what convolutional operations and pooling are.

What an inception does is combine different convolutional and pooling operations in parallel (these are called inception modules) so the network decides which of these parallen operations is the best for each layer. The first layers are convolutional, think about it as your eyes, they see shapes, colors, edges... and that is actually what these first layers see. Lastly you will have fully conected layers, such as the second picture you posted, that act as the classifier. Think about these as your brain. They get all these info from the eyes (convolutional layers) and 'realize' what they are actually seeing, i.e. my eyes see this round shape with hexagons and pentagons of different colors... my brain says wait a minute that's a soccer ball!

If it is not clear enough, we can furtherly discuss it. I am happy to help!